# Close all running projects in Visual Studio solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

In a scenario where you have a solution with multiple start-up projects, is there a way, from one running project, to programmatically close all other projects currently being debugged?

Another similar question: how can I, from one project, detect other projects currently being debugged? (I'm assuming if I can get a list of them, then I would be able to close them.)

Comment: I know I can click the button in the IDE; however, I would like to be able to to it programmatically.  It's not a show stopper if I can't, but it would help.

Comment: is this close or stop debugging ?

Comment: I want them to close, primarily.

Comment: I suggest you download the Visual Studio SDK, and learn how to programmatically execute commands.